# Terraform/GCP Timeout (and Resources Already Exist)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to provision GCP resources through Terraform, but it's timing out while also throwing errors saying that resources already exist (I've looked in GCP and through the CLI, and the resources do not exist).

```
 Error: Error waiting to create Image: Error waiting for Creating Image: timeout while waiting for state to become 'DONE' (last state: 'RUNNING', timeout: 15m0s)
│
│   with google_compute_image.student-image,
│   on main.tf line 29, in resource "google_compute_image" "student-image":
│   29: resource "google_compute_image" "student-image" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Error creating Firewall: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'projects/**-****-**********-******/global/firewalls/*****-*********-*******-*****-firewall' already exists, alreadyExists
│
│   with google_compute_firewall.default,
│   on main.tf line 46, in resource "google_compute_firewall" "default":
│   46: resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
```

Some (perhaps salient) details:

- I have previously provisioned these resources successfully using this same approach.
- My billing account has since changed.
- At another point, it was saying that the machine image existed (which, if it does, I can't see either in the console or the CLI).

I welcome any insights/suggestions.

**EDIT**
Including HCL; variables are defined in `variables.tf` and `terraform.tfvars`

```
provider google {
  region = var.region
}

resource "google_compute_image" "student-image" {
  name    = var.google_compute_image_name
  project = var.project

  raw_disk {
    source = var.google_compute_image_source
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "15m"
    update = "15m"
    delete = "15m"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  name    = "cloud-computing-project-image-firewall"
  network = "default"
  project = var.project

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"

    # 22: SSH
    # 80: HTTP
    ports = [
      "22",
      "80",
    ]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

  source = "./vm"
  name = "workspace-vm"

  project      = var.project
  image        = google_compute_image.student-image.self_link
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
}
```

There is a `vm` subdirectory with `main.tf`:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "student_instance" {
  name = var.name

  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone
  project      = var.project

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.image
      size  = var.disk_size
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      
    }
  }

  labels = {
    project = "machine-learning-on-the-cloud"
  }
}
```

...and `variables.tf`:

```
variable name {}

variable project {}

variable zone {
  default = "us-east1-b"
}

variable image {}

variable machine_type {}

variable disk_size {
  default = 20
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the Terraform HCL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe the resources were provisioned with Terraform but perhaps someone deleted them manually and so now your state file and what's actual doesn't match.  [`terraform refresh`](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/refresh) might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @glen-yu; tried that but got the same errors. I welcome any other ideas.